# Can't run adb on fedora 23

Tags: android, sdk, adb, fedora-23

Well I'm new at Linux and tried to start android development. Installed SDK and InteliJ IDE but wen I try to run Android project "ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill "adb" and click 'Restart'" message appears.  When I try to run adb from terminal in platform-tools it says "bash: ./adb: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error". I searched on google but couldn't find direct answer. Am I doing something completely wrong?

Comment: If adb not responding just write in console `adb kill-server` than `adb start-server`. If you're using command line please add also commands which you use, it may causes problems

Comment: the latest `adb` version is 64-bit only. are you trying to run it on a 32-bit system? downgrade your `platform-tools` package to version `23.0.1`

Comment: @AlexP. yes I use 32-bit system. Tried your suggestion works perfectly. thank you very much.